# В каких местах можно объявить плэйсхолдер?

Tags: java, spring

Пусть имеется конфигурация бинов в spring-beans.xml :

```
...
<bean id="fooBean" ... >
 <property name="fooProperty" value= "{fooProperty}">
<\bean>
```

В каких местах можно этот плэйсхолдер объявить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- В spring-beans.xml
- в другой XML, которую вы должны будете импортировать в spring-beans.xml
- В другой XML, в которой будет импортироваться spring-beans.xml
- В WEB.xml, если будет перечислен список xml в которых используется плейсхолдер